# How to check if view component exists before rendering in razor view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

ASP.NET Core has the [View Components](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html) mechanism for reusing parts of views. You can include the view component in a razor template file using `Component.InvokeAsync` call:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyComponent", new { data = 1 })
```

If view component with given name doesn't exist an `InvalidOperationException` exception is thrown.

```
InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'MyComponent' could not be found.
```

I would like to know how can i check if view component exist before rendering in razor view. Ideally something like:

```
@if (Component.Exists("MyComponent")
{
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyComponent", new { data = 1 })
}
else
{
    <p>Component not found</p>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject `IViewComponentSelector` into your view to check if component exists:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.IViewComponentSelector selector

@if (selector.SelectComponent("MyComponent")!= null)
{
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("MyComponent", new { data = 1 })
}
else
{
    <p>Component not found</p>
}
```

Comment: This corroborates the error I get that it does not find it, but I don't know why because it does not give any other clue why it is not finding the component. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902264/viewcomponent-in-external-assembly-cannot-be-found

Answer (score 2):

@adem answer may be the most correct for your question, but you can add compile time safety and invoke the view component by his class name.
I believe it's a cleaner solution.

Two options for **view component definition**:

1 - Remove the ViewComponent sufix

```
public class MyComponent : ViewComponent
```

2 - Add a [ViewComponent] attribute

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "MyComponent")]
public class MyComponentViewComponent : ViewComponent
```

**To invoke the component**:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(MyComponent))
```

If the component doesn't exist, a compile error is thrown.